# Internl Server Error after using Itextsharp

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part

when i try to use Itextsharp to create a pdf file from a webpart in sharepoint 2010 i get internal error on the 4 line of my code(Document) :

```
[WebMethod]
       public static string PrintReq(string ID, string Nature)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DataTable.pdf");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            **Document pdfDoc = Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);**
            return "true";
        }
```

Comment: Did you add additional assemblies to your web part?

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I had this problem when I used Itextsharp to create pdf file from custom web.

**Reason:** I did not add assembly reference in package.

**Solution:**  [Including additional assemblies in the WSP with Visual Studio SharePoint development tools](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/)

You have to do this always whenever you work with third party dll.

Comment: i don't have the control project in my solution

Comment: control project means what?